# If you take any square, and add one and minus one to one of the factors, is it always one less? Like $4^2$ is $16$, then $3\times5$ is $15$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Has there been a study done about this? I feel like a genius but it’s too simple to have not ever been thought of.

Comment: $(a+1)(a-1)=a^2-1$, or more generally the difference of squares identity $(a-b)(a+b)$ $=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: It's as dxiv says, but I also stumbled onto it myself before being told it, and felt really smart and cool for having discovered it, so in my books you are smart and cool too!

Comment: The power of algebra!

Comment: It's definitely a very cool fact to think about.